# Swagger UI Post and Put problem in relational database

Tags: asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, relational-database, swagger-ui

I am new at .NET Core. I am trying to develop sample API project but i realized a problem on the last project.Firstly i want to show my entities;

```
public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}


public class Enrollment
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see i am using two tables and there is a relation between 2 tables.
HttpGet and HttpDelete methods are Ok. The problem is;
when i tried to post a new record,swagger wants me to sent these datas:

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIpsv.png)

and whatever i do, i get this mistake:
[Swagger Fault image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAy4P.png)

Why i get this fault and why swagger wants me to send relational table datas?

Thanks for answer

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. When i try to use entities layer directly to match tables in SQL, i get this mistake. The problem is; API don't need ICollection properties that using for database diagrams, I mean, use entity layer directly isn't enough. I realized that have to use Dto Objects. I want to show model that required:

```
 public class Student
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
}

 public class Enrollment
    {
        public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
        public int CourseID { get; set; }
        public int StudentID { get; set; }
        public Student Student { get; set; }
    }


    public class StudentDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstMidName { get; set; }
    public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
}

public class EnrollmentDto
{
    public int EnrollmentID { get; set; }
    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
}
```

So, i used Dto objects to match API with Database

Answer (score 0):

This is new feature in .Net6. You also can change your code like below in

```
public ICollection<Enrollment>？ Enrollments { get; set; }
```

[Create the application and enable nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/nullable-reference-types#create-the-application-and-enable-nullable-reference-types)

---

You need to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson` package.

If your project is .Net 5. You can add `AddNewtonsoftJson` like below in your `Startup.cs` file.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...    
   services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
}
```

If your project is .Net 6. You can add `AddNewtonsoftJson` like below in your `Program.cs` file.

```
...
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson();
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found solve the problem. But i note your solution. I wil try when i need it again.

Comment: @atmaca I found the root cause for this issue,  Dto is not the only way to solve the issue.

Comment: I'll test new project within a week. I'll validate and share results with you.

Comment: I tried it in another project and it doesn't work. Probably you didn't get the problem or i couldn't explain well